# passing datetime as a variable to a stored procedure from an aspx page

Tags: asp.net, sql, datetime, variables, stored-procedures

I have the following code, and I am trying to pass datetime as a variable to a stored procedure.  I have tried several different things with no luck.  Any idea as to get date to pass to "@LVDate", and time to pass to "@LVTime"

```
   string connectionString = "server=abc;database=abc;uid=abc;pwd=1234";
   SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
   string procedureString = "LV_Insert";
   SqlCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
   mySqlCommand.CommandText = procedureString;
   mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@LVDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
   mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@LVTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
   mySqlConnection.Open();
   mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
   mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = mySqlCommand;
   mySqlConnection.Close();
```

Also, I need to get them to pass in the following formats:

```
{0:MM/dd/yyyy},{0:HH:mm:ss}
```

Comment: What are the column types for LVDate and LVTime ?? If you want to pass them in in that format it looks suspiciously like they may be strings??

Comment: Please show the definition of your stored procedure. In particular, we need to see how the parameters are declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of error are you getting?  It could be that DateTime.Now is not in the correct format that your stored procedure requires.  Use String.Format;

```
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy", DateTime.Now);
String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss", DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Although your method does work, I found my error to be a simple and boneheaded one.  The types set in the sproc were different than datetime.  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

```
 string connectionString = "server=abc;database=abc;uid=abc;pwd=1234";
   SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
   string procedureString = "LV_Insert";
   SqlCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
   mySqlCommand.CommandText = procedureString;
   mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add( new SqlParameter("@LVDate", DateTime.Now));
   mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LVTime", DateTime.Now));
   mySqlConnection.Open();
   mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
   mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = mySqlCommand;
   mySqlConnection.Close();
```